# Which reward/benefits card is the best value for money in Australia?

Tags: credit-card, australia, benefits, reward-program

As per the [question this is based off](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/405/which-reward-benefits-credit-card-is-the-best-value-for-the-money-in-canada):

> Which card do you use and why? Some cards are similar but some not.
>   This will also be affected by personal preference, so indicate why you
>   chose a certain card vs. another e.g. if you like to travel then you
>   may avoid the grocery redemption cards but there are often more than
>   one type of travel card available.

Comment: I found this topnotch website: http://www.creditcardfinder.com.au. The only thing I dislike is how it duplicates posts occasionally for search engine optimisation purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I assess when looking at new credit cards is whether it has no annual fee, the second thing I look at is how long the interest free period is. I always pay my credit card off in full just before the due date. Any rewards program is a bonus. My main credit card is with CBA, I have a credit limit of $20K and pay no annual fee. I get a bonus point for every $ I spend on it, for which I exchange for store gift cards to help with my everyday spending. Approximately 3500 point would get me a $25 gift card. But my main reward with the card is the interest I save by keeping my own money in a Home Loan Offset account whilst I spend with the Bank's money. Then I pay the full amount off by the due date so I do not pay any interest on the credit card.

I only use my credit cards for purchases I would usually make anyway and to pay bills, so my spending would be the same with or without a credit card. I can usually save over $500 each year off my Home Loan interest and get about $350 worth of gift cards each year. If I didn't have any Home Loans then I would keep my money in a high interest depost account so I would be increasing my interest payments each year.

Sure you can probably get credit cards with more generous rewards programs, but how much are you paying each year in annual fees, and if you don't have an interest free period and you don't pay off all the amount due each month how much are you paying in interest on the card? This is what you need to way up when looking at rewards programs on offer. Nothing is for free, well almost nothing !